# How to set a range of elements in an stl vector to a particular value?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, variable-assignment

I have a vector of booleans.  I need to set its elements from n-th to m-th to `true`.  Is there an elegant way to do this without using a loop?

Edit:  Tanks to all those who pointed out the problems with using `vector<bool>`.  However, I was looking for a more general solution, like the one given by jalf.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`std::fill` or `std::fill_n` in the `algorithm` header should do the trick.

```
 // set m elements, starting from myvec.begin() + n to true
std::fill_n(myvec.begin() + n, m, true);

// set all elements between myvec.begin() + n and myvec.begin() + n + m to true
std::fill(myvec.begin() + n, myvec.begin() + n + m, true);
```

Answer (score 6):

Vector of bool.
Sends shivers down my spine.

Have you looked at:
    std::bitset        (for fixed size flag sets)
    boost::dynamic_bitset (for dynamic size flag sets)

Set the bottom 8 bits in a row:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::bitset<12>      flags;
    flags   |= 0x0FF;

    std::cout << flags;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have already realized the folly of using vector<bool>, and I switched to vector<char>.  I was actually looking for a more general solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

Not to the best of my knowledge. You could try to use one of the algorithms like std::for_each, std::replace or std::fill to hide to fact that you're looping over the element range, but looping you will be.

Given that you said you're using a vector of booleans - if you're using the specialisation std::vector you might want to read the section "what about bool" in [this article by Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/050.htm).

Comment: I realize there is always a loop under the hood.  I was looking for a syntactically elegant way to hide it.

Comment: Thanks for the warning about vector<bool>, by the way.